# How can I get the user who posted in a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find out the user who posted each post in a Facebook group. I'm able to get the posts from the group:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}/feed
```

but the user who posted each one is not included in the info.

Comment: You need to specifically ask for the fields you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask for the fields, else you will only get default ones:

```
{group_id}/feed?fields=message,from
```

Available fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post